# Resource files are not added to the application on electron

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I am trying to add an executable file to an application that I am making using vuejs and electron so that I can run it on the user's computer from the application.

But after building and running on the user's computer, this folder with the program does not appear in the resources folder of my program.

My vue.config.js

```
pluginOptions: {
        electronBuilder: {
            extraResources: [
                {
                    "from": "extraResources/SumatraPDF-3.4.6-64.exe",
                    "to": "extraResources/SumatraPDF-3.4.6-64.exe"
                }
            ],
            win: {
                target: "portable"
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem

```
module.exports = defineConfig({
    transpileDependencies: true,
    pluginOptions: {
        electronBuilder: {
            builderOptions: {
                extraResources: [
                    {
                        "from": "extraResources/SumatraPDF-3.4.6-64.exe",
                        "to": "extraResources/SumatraPDF-3.4.6-64.exe"
                    }
                ],
                win: {
                    target: "portable"
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).